# How to pass variables between methods in the same class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I don't think I'm using class variables correctly.  Inside the ClientFormPage class, I initialize the active_form to 'f1_form'.  After I post the first form, I'd like to advance the active_form to 'f2_form', however it keeps resetting to 'f1_form'.  What is the best way to do this?

```
class ClientFormPage(PageHandler):
    active_form = 'f1_form'

    def render_form(self, f1='hidden', f2='hidden', **kw):
        self.render('clientforms.html', form1=f1, form2=f2, **kw)

    def get(self):
        self.render_form(f1='')

    def get_form2(self):
        self.render_form(f2='')

    def post(self):
        if self.active_form == 'f1_form':
            foo = self.request.get('foo')
            if not foo:
                self.render_form(f1_form='', foo=foo, 
                                 foo_error='has-error has-feedback')
            else:
                self.active_form = 'f2_form' # This assignment is not sticking
                self.get_form2()
                return

        if self.active_form == 'f2_form':
            bar = self.request.get('bar')
            if not bar:
                self.render_form(f1_form='', bar=bar, 
                                 bar_error='has-error has-feedback')
            else:
                self.active_form = 'f3_form'
                self.get_form3()
                return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code and comment well, You want to preserve state (active_form) between requests. To do this you have to use cookies.

You cannot save state in your webapp2 request handler class between requests. For every request a new handler class is created.

See the docs: [http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2%5fextras/sessions.html)

An alternative approach is to save the name of your active form in a hidden input of your HTML form.

```
<input type="hidden" name ="active_form" value="{{ active_form }}" >
```

Comment: This hidden input approach looks like exactly what I'm looking for, however it does not seem to work for me.  I've added this to my html template:    <input type="hidden" name ="f1_form" value="{{ active_form }}">.  I've also added this under my ClientFormPage class:        def post(self):
        active_form = self.request.get('active_form')
        self.response.write('Active Form: ' + active_form)

Comment: When I view the final write, it only displays 'Active Form: ' with no active_form value showing up.  I've not figured out where the value went.  Am I missing something with the hidden input?

Comment: It should be easy to debug. First look in your HTML form if the hidden input holds the active form value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__init__` magic method

```
class ClientFormPage(PageHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_form = 'f1_form'
```

This will allow you to have *instance* specific attributes, instead of class attributes as you have in your original code.

Quick demo on the difference:

[Python - why use "self" in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475871/python-why-use-self-in-a-class)

Comment: I just deleted my class variable line and replaced it with the two __init__ lines. I'm not clear how webapp2 calls this, but I get a TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given).  This prompted me to change to def __init__(self, foo, bar).  This time, I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'.  I'm not sure if I've provided enough to figure this out.  Anything sound obvious?

Comment: @bholben It looks like `PageHandler` objects are passed arguments when instantiated. Change the definition to `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):` and insert before your attribute creation `super(PageHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass(object):

def __init__(self):

def helper(self, jsonInputFile):
    values = jsonInputFile['values']
    ip = values['ip']
    username = values['user']
    password = values['password']
    return values, ip, username, password

def checkHostname(self, jsonInputFile):
   values, ip, username, password = self.helper
   print values
   print '---------'
   print ip
   print username
   print password
```

the init method initializes the class. the helper function just holds some variables/data/attributes and releases them to other methods when you call it. Here jsonInputFile is some json. the checkHostname is a method written to log into some device/server and check the hostname but it needs ip, username and password for that and that is provided by calling the helper method.